# How to autopopulate an Input field based on the selection of a dropdown value in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-ui, angular-forms

I am trying to auto populate an input field based on the selected value of a dropdown. The following is the code and it is not working. Please suggest.

```
<form [formGroup]="employeeForm" (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit()">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                            <mat-label>Employee ID</mat-label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Employee ID" required formControlName="employeeidControl" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto1">
                            <mat-autocomplete #auto1="matAutocomplete">
                                <mat-option *ngFor="let employee of employees" [value]="employee.id">
                                    {{ employee.id }}
    
                                </mat-option>
                            </mat-autocomplete>
                            <mat-error>
                                Employee ID is required
                            </mat-error>
                        </mat-form-field>
    
                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                            <mat-label>Employee Name</mat-label>
                            <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Employee Name" value="{{employeeidControl.name}}" required 
                            formControlName="employeenameControl">
                           
                            <mat-error>
                                Employee Name is required
                            </mat-error>
                        </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Comment: You should be able to read it of your form.. but you haven’t shown your formGroup..

Comment: I updated the form

Comment: I think employeeForm.get(‘ employeeidControl’).value should work?

Comment: I understood. Its writing only IDs...but I want to write the relative names of the IDs

Comment: Your putting the id in the form. So you can out the whole object in there instead and read the name value

Comment: any suggestions...how to do?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to fill in the Name field based on the selected ID?
Maybe in your mat-option put click event and pass the name to the ts. So:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let employee of employees" [value]="employee.id" (click)="test(employee.name)"> {{ employee.id }} </mat-option>
```

and in ts:

```
  test(employeeName){
    this.employeeForm.get('employeenameControl').patchValue(employeeName)
  }
```

Comment: But I want to populate the employee name value in input field

Comment: you tried the code above? it populate the field 'employeenameControl' with the employee name based no the selected ID. So if you select "id 1" the field it fills up with "nameemployee 1" (for example)

Comment: Ok. Got it. Will let you know.